# How can make more yellow point for sculpting

Tags: workflow, sculpting

[image: point1]

[image: point2]
[image: Youtube Tutorial]

I am a newbie to Blender. I try to make the figure of the body.
I follow all instruction from this video [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/4TwWWTj2AMI).
(slow down 0.25 to follow).After finish basic figure turn to the part of sculpting. I am only have four points for grab. The video have more points for grab.
How is it possible to start with a normal cube that has more points like the ico sphere ?
What wrong of my setting?

Comment: you can go in Edit mode, select all and right click > Subdivide. Then in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view) increase the cut number and put the Smooth value at 1

Comment: I have to disagree. It's the Subdivision modifier that you need to apply. If you additionally subdivide the cube manually you will end up with a bazillion of vertices. More than you will ever need (=bad performance). Of course, you can remove the modifier and subdivide it manually. That's ok. But not both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **apply the *Subdivision Surface* modifiers** of the cubes before you can sculpt the high poly mesh.

Go to the *Modifiers* tab (right side of screenhot 2 below), open the drop-down menu right next to the modifier's name (*Subdivison*) and choose *Apply* -or- hover the mouse over the modifier and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

The modifier takes the base mesh (the cube), subdivides the mesh, and outputs a sphere-like mesh that you see. In *Sculpt* and *Edit* mode you can only modify the base mesh (the cube).

Turn on the *Wireframe* in the *Overlays* menu:

[image: wireframe overlay]

... and switch to *Edit* mode:

[image: edit mode]

Here you see the base mesh that you can edit and sculpt, and the output of the modifier at the same time. The crosses of the black wireframe indicate the points where you can grab a yellow point in *Sculpt* mode.

[image: yellow grab point]

After you have applied the modifier you will have a lot more points to work with.