# Sculpting and separating

Tags: sculpting

I am *Sculpt* mode. Snake hook, scrape and smooth brushes do nothing to the mesh.

How do I move the mesh so I am sculpting?

I selected pieces of the mesh and pressed <kbd>P</kbd> to separate them. However the separated piece becomes nothing. The vertex is selected and not everything.

How do you separate pieces you see?
[image]I did apply the subdivision modifier and it screwed up the mesh. Moving the mesh in sculpt mode does nothing anyway. See the mesh and my settings. How do i so it does something when i move the mesh?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. That's hard to tell without more info. Have you added a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and but not applied it? Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/238582/107598 - if this link doesn't help, add a screenshot of the mesh and the modifiers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers work top-down. It's a good idea to apply them from top to bottom. Also note that you can only sculpt the base mesh (=the mesh without modifiers.). This is reason why it doesn't work. I guess your base mesh is only a few edges extruded by the *Skin* modifier.

Long story short, apply all modifiers: first the *Mirror*,  then the *Skin*, and finally, the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Now, you can sculpt the mesh. For symmetry you can enable the X-mirror option in the *Sculpt* mode.